# Type inference for integral template parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I have created a type that holds a unique identity of a method

```
template <typename Method, Method method>
struct identity {
};
```

So I can describe methods in a distinctive way, even if they have the same signature

```
struct Class {
    void foo() {}
    void bar() {}
};

typedef identity<decltype(&Class::foo), &Class::foo> foo_identity;
typedef identity<decltype(&Class::bar), &Class::bar> bar_identity;

std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_same<foo_identity, bar_identity>::value << std::end;
// prints "false"
```

Since the method of instantiation the identity is too verbose, as both names are used twice, it can be shortened with:

```
#define GEN_IDENTITY(NAME) identity<decltype(&NAME), &NAME>
GEN_IDENTITY(Class::foo)
```

But is there a way to deduce it without the use of a macro? Or maybe there is some other way to get a type that distinctively describes a method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But is there a way to deduce it without the use of a macro?

At the moment, no. There's a proposal for adding a construct in the language that will make non type template argument deductible just like `auto` ([N4469](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4469.html))

But for now,  you can simplify identity with that instead:

```
template<typename T, T t>
using identity = std::integral_constant<T, t>;
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for the link to the proposal. Hope it's gets added to the standard sometime.